# Java (and Android) - Weak Property Setter Attribute

Tags: java, properties

In Objective-C, any property can have a weak attribute which mean it doesn't own the passed object. If this object becomes nil (or null in Java for that matter), then this property wil be nil (or null) too. The object where this property is, **doesn't own the passed object**.

Now in Java, how can I make that?

**Update:**

To make it more clear, here is what exactly happens. This is an Android app. I have an Fragment-A (inside Activity-A). Fragment-A passes itself to an object-B (the property name is requester. I use it to track how called object-B). Later on, when the user presses back on Activity-A, I remove Object-B. However, I receive "**android – Unable to destroy activity java.lang.NullPointerException**".

I suspected this a weak reference issue. That's why I asked my question.

**Update 2:** 
The crash has nothing to do with weak reference. However, it was nice to know how to implement and I did. Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will find http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html useful.

```
WeakReference<Object> ref = new WeakReference<Object>(new Object());
...
Object newRef = ref.get();
if ( newRef == null ) {
    //Use newRef reference to Object as needed
} else {
    //Object has been released by the GC
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify more with an example? That will be useful.

Comment: added a brief example

Comment: Aha, you use .get() to get the original object. If use newRef.getHashCode(), will I get a unique number everytime?

Answer (score 2):

In Java you can use a `WeakReference` for this.
Example:

```
WeakReference<Integer> myWeakInt = new WeakReference<Integer>(5);
```

An excerpt from the documentation:

> Suppose that the garbage collector determines at a certain point in
>   time that an object is weakly reachable. At that time it will
>   atomically clear all weak references to that object and all weak
>   references to any other weakly-reachable objects from which that
>   object is reachable through a chain of strong and soft references. At
>   the same time it will declare all of the formerly weakly-reachable
>   objects to be finalizable. At the same time or at some later time it
>   will enqueue those newly-cleared weak references that are registered
>   with reference queues.

You can read more in the official docs about weak references but I think [this](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/enicholas/archive/2006/05/understanding_w.html) article expains it better and in less words.

Comment: I tried this solution. The problem is that myWeakInt is considered a new object. How did I know? By using the hashCode() method. I need this object to be unique and original.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you don't need to know ownership for memory management as it has a reliable gabage collection that can also deal with cyclic references.

If you plan to use this in the context of serialization, you will find that Java's `WeakReference` is not `Serializable` and that Java's serialization mechanism is less advanced than that of Objective-C. It has no concept of weak serialized references that don't trigger serialization themselfs but remain valid if the referenced object was still serialized because of strong references from somewhere else. In Java you can only make the reference `transient` in these cases which means it will never be serialized and also not restored and then you need to restore the reference manually by implementing a `readObject` method which requires you to know about an alternative access path to the object. It's unfortunatly far more cumbersome than in Objective-C.

Comment: Although the GC is reliable, it's not in my case. I have an original Object-A that passes itself to Object-B. Later on, Object-B is released (by setting it to null and removing it from a container list). Object-A is affected and receives deallocation method. I know that because later when i try to access A, I got a crash.